# How to Revit export PDF by DesignAutomationV3 (Forge API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I try your code to export DWGs in blog Autodesk Forge. It is work very well, I get a zip with files dwgs. Now i try to export PDF but it not work, i just get a zip with no things. I think it problem maybe from Print Settings of Revit Sandbox. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you reference this [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-generate-dynamic-number-output-design-automation-revit-v3)?

After you successfully got the zip package of dwgs by calling Revit Design Automation Activity, you need to unzip the package, and then iterate each of the DWG file to call another AutoCAD Design Automation Activity which will convert the DWG file to PDF. You have to define the AutoCAD Design Automation Activity to convert DWG to PDF.

Comment: yes, this reference i used. Anyway to export PDF from Revit, not through AutoCad

Comment: The printing is not supported by Revit Design Automation, so I would suggest you to use AutoCAD design automation to export PDF from DWG which should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Design Automation For Revit doesn't support PDF export currently. It is not a problem from Print Settings of Revit Sandbox.
You can use the way mentioned by @Zhong Wu above to generate PDF.