# What are the best options to export Revit views to convert to PDF using the Forge Design Automation API?

Tags: pdf, autodesk-forge, revit-api, dwg, autodesk-designautomation

I'm testing the conversion of several Revit view sheets to PDF as @Zhong Wu mentioned in [How to Revit export PDF by DesignAutomationV3 (Forge API)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55548935)

The problem is that the result is quite different from the original, especially regarding hatches and 3D views.

I'm using default DWG export options, so... what are the recommended options to make the resulting PDF look more like the original Revit view?

In these screenshots you can see what I mean:
[image: DWGExport using Design Automation then PlotToDwg] and [image: the result I expected (print to PDF using Revit desktop)]

Comment: Could you provide some examples/screenshots of how the outputs are "different", and what output you'd expect instead?

Comment: Yes of course. I have edited the question to add some screenshots.

Comment: @zhong-wu might provide more details here, but here's another question: have you checked how the DWG output looks like before you convert it to PDF? I'm guessing it could be an issue of the PlotToPDF job.

Comment: Yes. The exported DWG has a layout that looks exactly like the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The default `PlotToPDF` Activity uses `EXPORT` built-in AutoCAD command, which is not the same as `PLOT` that includes the PC3 settings you expect (based on the images).

You may need to create a custom Activity with the exact PLOT settings you need, ans your AppBundle or Workitem can include a custom PC3.

Here is a starting script that you may use (adjust size and settings as you need):

```
-PLOT
;Detailed plot configuration? [Yes/No] <No>: 
Yes
;Enter a layout name or [?] <Model>:
Model
;Enter an output device name or [?] <None>:
DWG To PDF.pc3
;Enter paper size or [?] <ANSI A (11.00 x 8.50 Inches)>:
ANSI A (11.00 x 8.50 Inches)
;Enter paper units [Inches/Millimeters] <Inches>:
Inches
;Enter drawing orientation [Portrait/Landscape] <Portrait>: 
Landscape
;Plot upside down? [Yes/No] <No>:
No
;Enter plot area [Display/Extents/Limits/View/Window] <Display>: 
Extents
;Enter plot scale (Plotted Inches=Drawing Units) or [Fit] <Fit>:
Fit
;Enter plot offset (x,y) or [Center] <0.00,0.00>:

;Plot with plot styles? [Yes/No] <Yes>:
Yes
;Enter plot style table name or [?] (enter . for none) <>:
.
;Plot with lineweights? [Yes/No] <Yes>:
Yes
;Enter shade plot setting [As displayed/legacy Wireframe/legacy Hidden/Visualstyles/Rendered] <As displayed>:

;Enter file name <C:\Work\solids-Model.pdf>:
!name
;Save changes to page setup? Or set shade plot quality? [Yes/No/Quality] <N>:
No
;Proceed with plot [Yes/No] <Y>:
Yes
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try with a custom activity. Should I also use the .pcp file that is created along with the .dwg?

Comment: you should use all the files you would need to run it locally, and you can test with `accoreconsole.exe` (AutoCAD Console)